# If element class is equal to nav element value then hide element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamic nav so when an nav item is clicked it shows elements with the same class as nav value.

Jquery:

```
$('section nav a').on({
        click: function() {
            var navElement = $(this).val();
            if ( $('article').attr('class') != navElement ) {
        $(this).hide();
            }
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<section>
    <div class="inside">
        <nav> 
<a href="#" title="typografi&ombrydning">Typografi & Ombrydning</a> 
<a href="#" title="grafiskdesign">Grafisk design</a> 
<a href="#" title="grafik&billeder">Grafik & Billeder</a> 
<a name="Workflow" class="workflow" title="workflow" href="#">Workflow</a> </nav>
        <article class="typografi&ombrydning workflow"> <img src="images/imgtest.jpg" width="230" height="210">
            <h2>Aphyxion</h2>
            <p class="time">Marts 15, 2012</p>
            <p>Billeder fra koncerten med aphyxion og molested på elværket i helsingør</p>
            <a class="read_more" href="#">Læs mere...</a> </article>
        <article class="grafik&billeder"> <img src="images/imgtest.jpg" width="230" height="210">
            <h2>Aphyxion</h2>
            <p class="time">Marts 15, 2012</p>
            <p>Billeder fra koncerten med aphyxion og molested på elværket i helsingør</p>
            <a class="read_more" href="#">Læs mere...</a> </article>
        <article class="workflow"> <img src="images/imgtest.jpg" width="230" height="210">
            <h2>Aphyxion</h2>
            <p class="time">Marts 15, 2012</p>
            <p>Billeder fra koncerten med aphyxion og molested på elværket i helsingør</p>
            <a class="read_more" href="#">Læs mere...</a> </article>
        <article class="grafiskdesign grafik&billeder"> <img src="images/imgtest.jpg" width="230" height="210">
            <h2>Aphyxion</h2>
            <p class="time">Marts 15, 2012</p>
            <p>Billeder fra koncerten med aphyxion og molested på elværket i helsingør</p>
            <a class="read_more" href="#">Læs mere...</a> </article>
        <article class="workflow"> <img src="images/imgtest.jpg" width="230" height="210">
            <h2>Aphyxion</h2>
            <p class="time">Marts 15, 2012</p>
            <p>Billeder fra koncerten med aphyxion og molested på elværket i helsingør</p>
            <a class="read_more" href="#">Læs mere...</a> </article>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But i cant get it to work
Can you guys please help.

Best Regards

Comment: You need to show the HTML as well.

Comment: $('article') ?? it must be either $('.article') or $('#article')

Comment: @ubercooluk `<article>` is a valid HTML5 tag.

Comment: I've added the html.
The site is based on html5 for now.

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? It doesn't seem to make much sense as it is now. Hide the link if an article with the same name exists?

Comment: Whn i click the link in the nav that has the class workflow. it needs to hide all articles without the class workflow

Comment: @Juhana ohh yes sorry my bad !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for? Are you trying to show contents based on the navigation element clicked. If so take a look here? http://jsfiddle.net/cQt5p/. I would personally use data attributes as opposed to using classes to show and hide related elements.

Answer (score 2):

try -

```
$('section nav a').on({
        click: function() {
            var navElement = $(this).text();
            if ( $('article').hasClass(navElement) ) {
               $(this).hide();
            }
    }
});
```